# php pdf file output contents

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a list of PDF [myfile.pdf] files on a folder/dir called `example.com/uploaded/downloads/`

I need a user to download or view on the page a pdf file, however I do not want them to see the `uploaded` on the url, which is the best way to do it?
so users can click a link `example.com/downloads/`

I had a .htaccess code (since im not good at it) it got me no where

`RewriteRule ^downloads/([A-Za-z0-9-]+) /uploaded/downloads/$1 [L]`

I have tried PHP `header('... application/pdf');` not good either.

PLEASE NOT: `example.com` could change directory aswell e.g. `example.com/new_design/` therefore the dir would be `example.com/new_design/uploaded/downloads/` and users should be able to see `example.com/new_design/downloads/`

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the RewriteEngine turned on and try this slightly modified pattern.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^downloads/(.*)$ uploaded/downloads/$1 [L]
```

If you are still having trouble, try looking at the Apache log files. They may indicate a problem with permissions or the file path. The log file is usually located in /var/log/apache2.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]`I can't use base ... because i have this condition on it

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. What you are doing looks OK at a glance. I would comment out all your other rewrite rules and condition to try and debug the problem. Eliminate anything that could be conflicting with your new rule.